# Getting a view of a zarr array slice

Tags: python, numpy, zarr

I would like to produce a zarr array pointing to *part* of a zarr array on disk, similar to how `sliced = np_arr[5]` gives me a view into `np_arr`, such that modifying the data in `sliced` modifies the data in `np_arr`. Example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import zarr


arr = zarr.open(
    'temp.zarr',
    mode='a',
    shape=(4, 32, 32),
    chunks=(1, 16, 16),
    dtype=np.float32,
)
arr[:] = np.random.random((4, 32, 32))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
arr[2, ...] = 0  # works fine, "wipes" slice 2
ax[0].imshow(arr[2])  # all 0s

arr_slice = arr[1]  # returns a NumPy array — loses ties to zarr on disk
arr_slice[:] = 0
ax[1].imshow(arr[1])  # no surprises — shows original random data

plt.show()
```

Is there anything I can write instead of `arr_slice = arr[1]` that will make `arr_slice` be a (writeable) view into the `arr` array on disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [TensorStore](https://github.com/google/tensorstore) library is specifically designed to do this --- all indexing operations produce lazy views:

```py
import tensorstore as ts
import numpy as np
arr = ts.open({
  'driver': 'zarr',
  'kvstore': {
    'driver': 'file',
    'path': '.',
  },
  'path': 'temp.zarr',
  'metadata': {
    'dtype': '<f4',
    'shape': [4, 32, 32],
    'chunks': [1, 16, 16],
    'order': 'C',
    'compressor': None,
    'filters': None,
    'fill_value': None,
  },
}, create=True).result()
arr[1] = 42  # Overwrites, just like numpy/zarr library
view = arr[1] # Returns a lazy view, no I/O performed
np.array(view) # Reads from the view
# Returns JSON spec that can be passed to `ts.open` to reopen the view.
view.spec().to_json()
```

You can read more about the "index transform" mechanism that underlies these lazy views here:
https://google.github.io/tensorstore/index_space.html#index-transform
https://google.github.io/tensorstore/python/indexing.html

Disclaimer: I'm an author of TensorStore.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! 

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be with a custom store object. You could subclass [DirectoryStore](https://github.com/zarr-developers/zarr-python/blob/master/zarr/storage.py#L715) or whatever other base store your data are in and override the getitem / setitem methods. This is probably harder than you wish it were.

A better option would be to copy Xarray's `LazilyIndexedArray` types, which are a piece of magic by written by Stephan Hoyer: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/master/xarray/core/indexing.py#L516.
I think these do exactly what you want. They are not part of Xarray's public API, but IMO they are so useful they should actually be in a standalone package.

Also nice related blog post about this here:
https://medium.com/informatics-lab/creating-a-data-format-for-high-momentum-datasets-a394fa48b671

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed harder than I wished.  Jeremy's library is probably what I'll use for now. Do you think there is scope to revisit the eager getitem design of zarr-python? If so I would open an issue, but I realise this is a massive design change. But it could be an attribute set at creation-time, `lazy=False` (default)... But anyway the blog post and links are super useful. 

Comment: For future code archeologists, more discussion on Twitter: https://twitter.com/shoyer/status/1331020787155828738